# DataTables won't load on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

I am using DataTables on my current project, and for some reason when I run the application on my phone it will not load any of the data supplied by ajax and it gives me the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

However on my desktop computer, it works perfectly fine. I am using the bootstrap 4 version of DataTables and my app.js looks like the following

```
require( 'datatables.net-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4' );
```

I am instantiating the DataTable as follows within the view - using @stack to force it underneath the app.js include

```
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '{{ route('user.indexData') }}',
        },
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        oLanguage: {
            "sSearch": "Filter:",
            "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ user(s)",
            "sInfoEmpty": "No users to show",
            "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ users"
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id', responsivePriority: 1},
            { data: 'name', name: 'name', responsivePriority: 2 },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email', responsivePriority: 3 },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action', searchable: false, orderable: false, responsivePriority: 4 }
        ],
        "drawCallback": function () {
            $('.dataTables_paginate > .pagination').addClass('flex-wrap');
        }
    });
});
```

Is there anybody that has any clue on why it only gives me this error on my mobile device, and any possible fixes?

Comment: why did you tag php as a language? is the server in php? Even if that's the case, it's irrelevant because your error is client side.

Comment: Removed the tag @GyuhyeonLee, cheers.

Comment: also... we can't debug it for you; "~is not a function" is a very straightforward error.  `$('#users-table')` does not have a `DataTable()` method in it. Set up a breakpoint(Maybe open up the chrome devtools and set device as mobile) and see what `$('#users-table')` actually is, and see why there isn't whatever function you expected to exist. And after that, maybe you'll need to learn about closures and IIFEs. I'm not knowledgeable in DataTables library you talk about, but again, the error you posted is not a library error and more of a generic one. The browser just doesn't see (continued)

Comment: @GyuhyeonLee You should really read the question before you jump to conclusions. I clearly specified that this problem only persists on a mobile device, it works perfectly when tested on the desktop - no errors, no warnings. If i open the SAME url on my phone, then it spits out that error.

Comment: whatever method you wanted to use existing in the current object. The reason for that could vary. Library failed to load(although I don't know why you're using `require` here, it's not ES6 node.js and honestly it's just simpler to use `<script src="source.js"></script>` than to hope the clientside browser supports ES6 grammar.

Comment: Okay, if it does work on desktop it means it's not IIFE or closures then. It must be that the browser you're using on mobile doesn't use ES6, and you seem to have used the "require" sugar in the clientside javascript.

Comment: I am using webpack, to handle all the requirements. I am using the standard laravel stack. Also the browser I am using on my phone is Chrome.

Comment: Did you try using Devtools to simulate mobile? Does it persist there, or does it only happen on a physical mobile device you happen to be using?

Comment: It only happens on a physical mobile device.

Comment: again, I'm not specifically aware of the techs you're using, but it seems to me that the library(DataTables) is failing to load. `$('#users-table')` looks like jQuery, and DataTables is... well, a function. Exactly how is DataTables supposed to be attached to a random jQuery dom element? Is it when you load the DataTables library? (I don't know) If so, the "~ is not a function" is a very easy error - you seem to actually know code, and seem to have set up jsfiddle to catch that mobile device error log from a desktop. DataTables doesn't exist in that object. Finding out why it failed... (cont)

Comment: should be pretty straightfoward. set up a breakpoint where you're loading DataTables, and see if it loaded indeed. If it did, see why it didn't attach to the jquery element(if it does, I mean...). That's as far as I can help here.

Comment: Last thing, try using that webapp from IE 8 or whatever legacy browser you can get hands on. I'm betting it fails there too. (From IE11 devtools, you can set IE 6~11 from devtool menu to see how it holds up)

Comment: jQuery, is getting executed and works. But apparently DataTables does not attach to jQuery or $ - I don't really know why it does this ONLY on a mobile device or a significant older browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by adding "window.DataTables" infront of my require, this allowed the system to recognize the DataTables library even when it did not auto-discover it. Which I assume, as suggested by Gyuhyeon Lee in the comments, is due to an older version of the browser.

Here is the code that fixed it for me.

```
window.DataTables = require( 'datatables.net-bs4' );
```

I had solved the issue several times, but while working on the mobile device, it never dawned over me that the page was cached - resulting in the same error being spouted. So remember to clear your cache aswell.