# DataTable working on computer but not mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have data which fills a DataTable that works fine on desktop but on mobile the data doesn't load into the table. Using web inspector on mobile the error in console just says Load failed.

Only ideas I have had are the width of the div (#InstHolderHolder) that I am appending the table to is affecting how the data goes in and then a message in the table displays no data available in table.

**HTML**

```
<div id="instholderholder" class="row mt-2 p-2 border d-flex flex-column">
    <select class="form-select" style="width: 210px;" name="instselection" id="instselectionid"></select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
async function Institutions(inst) {

    var ku = await getit()
    var k = ku[0]
    var u = ku[1]

    $('#instholderholder').append('<div id="InstHolderHolder" class="col-12 col-lg-8"></div>');

    var responsing = await fetch(u + '/v4/13f-asset-allocation-date?apikey=' + k)
    var dating = await responsing.json()

    var ticker = $('#title').text()

    var response = await fetch(u + '/v4/institutional-ownership/institutional-holders/symbol-ownership?date=' + inst + '&symbol=' + ticker + '&page=0&apikey=' + k)
    var data = await response.json()

    var inst = document.getElementById('InstHolderHolder')

    instHeader = "<table id='insttable' class='table table-striped table-bordered border'><thead style='font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;'><th>cik</th><th>Date</th><th>Name</th><th>Weight in Fund</th><th>Percentage Change in Weight (%)</th><th>Ownership of Company</th><th>Percentage Change in Ownership (%)</th></thead>"
    instBody = "<tbody>"

    for (let index=0; index<data.length; index++) {
        let first = "<tr>" + "<td style='font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;'>" + data[index].cik + "</td>" +
        "<td style='font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;'>" + data[index].date + "</td>" +
        "<td><a style='text-decoration: none; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;' href='/institutions/" + data[index].cik + "'>" + data[index].investorName + "</td>" +
        "<td style='font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;'>" + parseFloat(data[index].weight).toFixed(2) + "</td>" + 
        "<td style='font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;'>" + parseFloat(data[index].changeInWeightPercentage).toFixed(2) + "</td>" +
        "<td style='font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;'>" + parseFloat(data[index].ownership).toFixed(2) + "</td>" + 
        "<td style='font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;'>" + parseFloat(data[index].changeInOwnershipPercentage).toFixed(2) + "</td>" + "</tr>"
        instBody += first
    };

    inst.innerHTML = "<h4>Changes in Institutional Ownership</h4>" + instHeader + instBody + "</tbody></table><table id='Datatable'></table>"

    var WindowWidth = window.innerWidth
  
    if (WindowWidth < 600) {
        $('#insttable').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true
        });
    }else {
        $('#insttable').DataTable();
    }
    
};
```

Problems with getting the DataTable working on mobile so far tried resizing the container div but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried using the mobile emulator in desktop browsers? Does it fail there? If so, you can use that console to debug it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943985/how-to-debug-javascript-code-with-mobile-browsers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511281/datatables-wont-load-on-mobile-devices